# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (2)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, mach-o

I'm getting 2 Mach-O Linker Errors in regards to the [CloudApp API](https://github.com/cloudapp/objective-c). I have been been searching for numerous answers in both StackOverflow, Apple's Developer forums, and elsewhere that would at least be remotely close to be problem, but they have not been very helpful. This has been boggling my mind for the past few days and I can't seem to fix it.

Here are the two errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLAPIEngine", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be appreciated. If you have any questions, just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you add the project?  Copy the source files?  Or add a subproject in Xcode?

Comment: I copied the source files; My project just wasn't recognizing "Cloud.h", so I decided to just copy the source files, which worked... until this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking in the framework as part of the build process

Build the cloud library first. Then ensure that the `libCloud.a` library is linked to your application

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this as the first problem!  +1